# FQL - Get news feed posts only without photos or videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, feed

I'm trying to get the facebook news feed without photos and videos using FQL, I'm already using this code to get the whole news feed with photos and videos.

Here's the FQL code

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed')AND is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 300
```

What I should to add in this code to get posts only without news feed?

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for the **stream** table at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

You can use the field **type** to specify which type of posts you want to see

```
The type of this story. Possible values are:
11 - Group created
12 - Event created
46 - Status update
56 - Post on wall from another user
66 - Note created
80 - Link posted
128 -Video posted
247 - Photos posted
237 - App story
257 - Comment created
272 - App story
285 - Checkin to a place
308 - Post in Group
```

like this

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0 AND type IN (80,237,257,272,285) ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 300
```